# Check if the string contains all inputs on the list

Tags: c#

I want to be able to check if the string contains all the values held in the list;
So it will only give you a 'correct answer' if you have all the 'key words' from the list in your answer.
Heres something i tired which half fails;(Doesn't check for all the arrays, will accept just one).
Code i tired:

```
 foreach (String s in KeyWords)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains(s))
            {
                correct += 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
                LoadUp();
            }
            else
            {
                incorrect += 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect.");
                LoadUp();
            }
        }
```

Essentially what i want to do is:

> Question: What is the definition of Psychology?

Key words in arraylist: **study,mental process,behaviour,humans**

> Answer: Psychology is the **study** of **mental process** and **behaviour** of **humans**

Now if and ONLY if the answer above contains all key words will my code accept the answer.
I hope i have been clear with this.

**Edit:** Thank you all for your help. All answers have been voted up and i thank everyone for quick answers. I voted up the answer that can be easily adapted to any code. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
// case insensitive check to eliminate user input case differences
var invariantText = textBox1.Text.ToUpperInvariant();
bool matches = KeyWords.All(kw => invariantText.Contains(kw.ToUpperInvariant()));
```

Answer (score 6):

This should help:

```
 string text = "Psychology is the study of mental process and behaviour of humans";
 bool containsAllKeyWords = KeyWords.All(text.Contains);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some of the LINQ methods like:

```
if(Keywords.All(k => textBox1.Text.Contains(k))) {
   correct += 1;
   MessageBox.Show("Correct");
} else {
   incorrect -= 1;
   MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
}
```

The [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534754.aspx) method returns true when the function returns true for all of the items in the list.