# Check how many instances of strings in a list

Tags: c#, math

Well I enquired about checking if certain keywords can be found in an list and if they are all there the question is correct. Found here: [Check if the string contains all inputs on the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728294/check-if-the-string-contains-all-inputs-on-the-list)

What I would like to also know is how many of the words are in the list, then divide it and get a percentage, so the user knows how accurately they answered each question.

```
        public String KeyWords_Found()
        {
            int Return_Value = 0;
            foreach (String s in KeyWords)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Contains(s))
                {
                    Return_Value++;
                }
            }
            int Holder = Return_Value / KeyWords.Count;
            int Fixed = Holder * 100;
            return  Fixed + "%";
        }
```

So what I want that code it do is check for all instances of keywords listed into the list `KeyWords`. Then get the percentage by dividing by the total amount of keywords and multiplying by 100. But it says that both values are 0 and i cant divide by 0. I'm not sure why they would be zero. Confused! Help!

Comment: Please show the code where you create and add values to `KeyWords` as it sounds like it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check, if `KeyWords` is empty or not

```
public String KeyWords_Found()
{
    if (KeyWords.Count == 0)
        return "0%";
    // rest of the code
}
```

**Alternatively** you could use Linq instead of writing your own method:

```
int nOfOccurences = KeyWords.Where(k => textBox1.Text.Contains(k)).Count();
```

make sure you are `using System.Linq;` for that to work.

You'll still need to check for `KeyWords.Count == 0` and compute the percentage yourself, though.

Comment: should be `Count()` as `Where(x)` return `IEnumerable` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use floating point maths instead of integer maths in your calculations.

```
int i=100;
int a=51;

(i/a)==0  //true, integer division sucks for calculating percentages

((double)i/a)==0 //false, actually equals ~1.96
```