# Check if list contains all words in string

Tags: c#

Well i was reading [Check if the string contains all inputs on the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728294/check-if-the-string-contains-all-inputs-on-the-list)
And tried it, but when i had something like a basic question such as 'Who discovered Austrlia'
and if i put the key words in the answer as 'captain,cook' it would say i got the question wrong.

Any idea what im doing wrong; code im using:

```
            GivenAnswer = textBox1.Text;
            String invariantText = textBox1.Text.ToUpperInvariant();
            bool matches = KeyWords.All(kw => invariantText.Contains(kw.ToUpperInvariant()));
                if (matches)
                {
                    correct++;
                    if (InstantResult) { MessageBox.Show("Questions Answered Correctly", "Answer Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); }
                }
                else
                {
                    incorrect++;
                    if (InstantResult) { MessageBox.Show("Question Answered Wrong, sorry!", "Answer Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk); }
                }
            Study_Helper.Form1.QuestionResults.Add(Question + "|" + (matches ? "true" : "false") + "|" + (Exact? "N/A" : KeyWords_Found()) + "|" + (Hint_Used ? "true" : "false") + "|" + GivenAnswer.ToLowerInvariant());
            LoadUp();
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Focus();
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, have you confirmed that `KeyWords` and `invariantText` contain expected values? Use the debugger or `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Make that an answer dude.
Because i did open a message box with results and i forgot to clear the 'KeyWords' arraylist before the next question loaded up<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the first comment on my question.
I relised i never actually cleared the arraylist, make sure you clear the arraylist after you do this check as to not get more values in your keyword list then wanted.

```
KeyWords.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, confirm that `KeyWords` and `invariantText` contain expected values. Use the debugger or `Console.WriteLine().`

This is where unit testing becomes valuable. NUnit or MSTest are available for C#/VS development.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment.
Thanks to that i relised i never actually cleared the arraylist<3 Works perfect now. 1000 thank you's!